# League\Commonmark + Drupal: Unable to find corresponding renderer for node type

Tags: php, drupal, markdown, thephpleague, commonmark

I'm trying to render markdown using League\Commonmark 2.3.8 with extensions in Drupal and I'm getting the following error when I try to render with extensions:

> Unable to find corresponding renderer for node type
> League\CommonMark\Node\Block\Document

Here's my code:

```
class FilterMarkdown extends FilterBase {

  /**
   * @var array The private config array.
   *
   * https://commonmark.thephpleague.com/2.3/configuration/.
   */
  private array $config = [
    // Allow because only the admin has markdown access.
    'html_input' => 'allow',
    'allow_unsafe_links' => false,
  ];

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function process($text, $langcode): FilterProcessResult {
    $converter = new MarkdownConverter($this->createEnvironment());

    $converted_text = $converter->convert($text);

    return new FilterProcessResult("$converted_text");
  }

  /**
   * Generate an environment with all the extensions we need.
   */
  private function createEnvironment(): Environment {
    $environment = new Environment($this->config);
    $environment->addExtension(new ExternalLinkExtension());
    $environment->addExtension(new HeadingPermalinkExtension());
    $environment->addExtension(new StrikethroughExtension());
    $environment->addExtension(new TableExtension());

    return $environment;
  }

}
```

The problem is related to the way I am creating the [environment](https://commonmark.thephpleague.com/2.3/customization/environment/).  I know this because I rewrote process() as follows and markdown conversion works as expected:

```
  public function process($text, $langcode): FilterProcessResult {
    $converter = new CommonMarkConverter($this->config);

    $converted_text = $converter->convert($text);

    return new FilterProcessResult("$converted_text");
  }
```

I also removed all the `addExtension` lines and got the same error, so the problem is `new Environment($this->config)`.

I then tried initializing with no config: `new Environment([])`, but I still get the same error.

So what am I doing wrong?

(Drupal has a [markdown module](https://www.drupal.org/project/markdown), but I can't use it because I am moving my site to Drupal 10 and the module isn't compatible.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to also add the `CommonMarkCoreExtension` or `InlinesOnlyExtension` too as those provide the parsers and renderers for things like `Document`, `Paragraph`, and `Text` nodes. (Alternatively you could manually register the individual parsers and renderers yourself if you need more control over what syntax you want to include or exclude).